# Scriban Rendering Parameters - how to get the value from Droplist?

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am trying to get the value from the `Rendering Parameters` in Scriban in order to render some new logic. Basically, I want to allow the content editors to choose what colour of the button they will have. I have set up the **class names** for the colours and everything regarding the frontend part. Now, I only need to get the values from the Droplist since I am using that as a rendering parameters type of datasource.

Here is what I mean by this:

[image]

This is the **component properties** for this specific component called **Sign up section**. When user selects for example `Gold` from the **Droplist** i want to change the button colour to gold.

This is datasource:
[image]

Here is the template for rendering parameters:
[image]

And here is the `Scriban` template:

```
{{
    buttonColor = ""
    if (sc_parameter "Button Color" != null) 
        parameter =  sc_parameter 'Button Color' 
        buttonColor = ".button-new-sign {{parameter}}"
    end
    backgroundColor = sc_parameter 'Background Color'
    icon = sc_parameter 'Icon'
}}



<div class="call-to-action call-to-action-fullwidth call-to-action-signup" style="background-color: {{backgroundColor}};">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="call-to-action-content">
                    <div class="row flex-md-nowrap justify-content-center">
                        <div
                            class="col-12 col-md-auto flex-shrink-1 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <svg class="call-to-action-icon icon icon-email">
                                <use xlink:href="#icon-email"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <h2 class="call-to-action-title text-center text-md-left">
                                {{sc_field  i_item "Sign Up Text"}}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto text-center my-auto">
                        {{ if sc_parameter "Button Color" != "" }}
                        <div class="call-to-action-button {{buttonColor}}">
                        {{ sc_beginfield i_item 'Sign Up Link' [['text', ' ']]}}
                        {{ sc_link_text i_item 'Sign Up Link' }}
                        {{ sc_endfield }} 
                        </div>
                        {{else}}
                        <div class="call-to-action-button button button-white">
                            {{ sc_beginfield i_item 'Sign Up Link' [['text', ' ']]}}
                            {{ sc_link_text i_item 'Sign Up Link' }}
                            {{ sc_endfield }} 
                            </div>
                        {{ end }}       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to get the `Value` field from the Colors item, or I can not do that since I am using droplist. Does anyone suggest any other way of doing this?

Comment: Why not using the ootb styles feature? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-style-for-a-rendering.html  I think this might be easier than writing it all yourself

Comment: I am not using that since I want to only use the class name on button inside the Sign Up Section. The button is not a component inside the Sitecore, so that I can add the styles on it

Comment: So you are defining a style..  you really should use styling. It would save you a lot of (duplicate) code as well ...

Answer (score 2):

`Droplist` fields always store their values as the name of the items. You should use `Droplink` instead of Droplist.

Getting value in `Scriban template`

```
<div>This rendering is in the '{{ sc_parameter 'Placeholder' }}' placeholder.<div>
```

Reference :
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html

Code for getting value without `Scriban template` :

```
var getValue = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters[" name of the field"];
var valueDetails = RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(Guid.Parse(getValue)));
var finalvalue = valueDetails["Value"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can something similiar be achievable using Scriban? Or should I just use for example `.Value` since it is the name of the field, when editing in Scriban?

Comment: Try to use droplink in field and use this code to get the value `{{ sc_parameter 'Placeholder' }}`

Comment: This will not work, this only shows the ID of the item

Comment: have you tried like this {{ sc_parameter 'Button Color' }} after changing in the field type ?

Comment: I did, and it only showed me item ID of the lets say "Gold" Color, but not the field called `Value` inside that item

Comment: If you are not getting the value through it then you can do one think update the same name of the item (In display name  of the item , you can use the 'Gold' in item )which you have in value and use droplist field value in template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134877/discussion-between-ashish-and-samke11).

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement something similar and I decided to write my own custom Scriban extension.

The code below will get the value from a **Droplink** field (which is specified in the Scriban), retrieves the selected item and returns the value from the **Value** field.

```
 public class ValueHelperFunction : IGenerateScribanContextProcessor
{
    private delegate string ValueHelperDelegate(string field);

    public ValueHelperFunction()
    {
    }
    public void Process(GenerateScribanContextPipelineArgs args)
    {
        args.GlobalScriptObject.Import("sc_getvalue", new ValueHelperDelegate(GetValue));
    }

    private string GetValue(string field)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.Parameters[field]))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var itemId = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.Parameters[field];

        return Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(itemId))?["Value"] ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And you should create a patch config.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore>       
    <pipelines>
        <generateScribanContext>
            <processor type="Namespace.ValueHelper, Namespace" resolve="true" />            
        </generateScribanContext>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Finally, you can use your new extension in your scriban template:

```
{{ sc_getvalue 'Button Color' }}
```